# Render simple html to a canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to render simplistic text format html (p, strong, em, headline tags etc) to a canvas.

I have looked into parsing library's such as jsoup but i need to iterate in the dom tree "linear" some how.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Thanks
/R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by parsing trough the html tree structure using jsoup then implementing a simple canvas class to draw the text :)